# Native Java crash Linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm, java-native-interface

I am trying to run an application that uses JNI on a Linux server and the application crashes.

I get the following crash report (excerpt)

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000003543067974, pid=27670, tid=140285572105984
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x67974]  fwrite+0x34
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I tried the application on my Mac and it runs OK. However, it crashes on the server. Both machines use Java 1.8 x64

I have checked the log and narrowed down the problem to the following command:

```
Stack: [0x00007f96c7a14000,0x00007f96c7b15000],  sp=0x00007f96c7b133b0,  free    space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x67974]  fwrite+0x34
```

I assume this does not have to do with my application as it runs fine on my machine. Any ideas?

**Update**

```
The problematic frame is outside my code:
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  xxxx.PN_PrintToFile(JLjava/lang/String;)V+0
```

**Update 2 (detailed crash report)**

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000354306798a, pid=23360, tid=140577572452096
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x6798a]  fwrite+0x4a
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fdac0008000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=23364, stack(0x00007fdac434f000,0x00007fdac4450000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=128 (), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000012, RBX=0x00007fdac0378080, RCX=0x00007fdac0378080,        RDX=0x6b6f6f4c24726573
RSP=0x00007fdac444e420, RBP=0x0000000000000012, RSI=0x0000000000000001, RDI=0x00007fdac04fea20
R8 =0x00007fdac04fea20, R9 =0x00007fdac444f700, R10=0x0000000000000012, R11=0x00007fdac04fea33
R12=0x0000000000000001, R13=0x0000000000000012, R14=0x00007fdac444e510, R15=0x00007fdac0008000
RIP=0x000000354306798a, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fdac444e420)
0x00007fdac444e420:   00007fdac444e500 00007fdac00081e0
0x00007fdac444e430:   00007fdac04fea20 00007fdac444e500
0x00007fdac444e440:   00007fdac0378080 00007fda30dc7a5d
0x00007fdac444e450:   00007fdac444e5c8 00007fdaa919c988
0x00007fdac444e460:   00007fdac444e4e0 0000000000000000
0x00007fdac444e470:   00007fdaa919c988 00007fdab0bcab2e
0x00007fdac444e480:   00007fdaa91980fa 00000000000000b6
0x00007fdac444e490:   00007fdaa9198110 00007fdac0008000
0x00007fdac444e4a0:   00007fdac444e4a0 0000000000000000
0x00007fdac444e4b0:   00007fdac444e510 00007fdaa919cbf0
0x00007fdac444e4c0:   0000000000000000 00007fdaa919c988
0x00007fdac444e4d0:   0000000000000000 00007fdac444e500
0x00007fdac444e4e0:   00007fdac444e558 00007fdab0bbf2e0
0x00007fdac444e4f0:   000000008030bc80 00007fdab0bc6c18
0x00007fdac444e500:   00000005801e73e0 00007fdac0378080
0x00007fdac444e510:   00007fdaa9198110 00007fdac444e518
0x00007fdac444e520:   00007fdaa9199ea5 00007fdac444e570
0x00007fdac444e530:   00007fdaa919aaa8 0000000000000000
0x00007fdac444e540:   00007fdaa9199eb0 00007fdac444e500
0x00007fdac444e550:   00007fdac444e568 00007fdac444e5b8
0x00007fdac444e560:   00007fdab0bbf2e0 00000005801e73e0
0x00007fdac444e570:   0000000080358e20 00007fdac444e578
0x00007fdac444e580:   00007fdaa9199d72 00007fdac444e5d0
0x00007fdac444e590:   00007fdaa919aaa8 0000000000000000
0x00007fdac444e5a0:   00007fdaa9199d80 00007fdac444e568
0x00007fdac444e5b0:   00007fdac444e5c8 00007fdac444e618
0x00007fdac444e5c0:   00007fdab0bbf2e0 00000005801e73e0
0x00007fdac444e5d0:   0000000080358e20 00007fdac444e5d8
0x00007fdac444e5e0:   00007fdaa91980fa 00007fdac444e630
0x00007fdac444e5f0:   00007fdaa919a430 0000000000000000
0x00007fdac444e600:   00007fdaa9198110 00007fdac444e5c8
0x00007fdac444e610:   00007fdac444e628 00007fdac444e678 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000354306798a)
0x000000354306796a:   cb 4d 85 ed 0f 84 ec 00 00 00 66 83 39 00 78 4a
0x000000354306797a:   48 8b 91 88 00 00 00 64 4c 8b 0c 25 10 00 00 00
0x000000354306798a:   4c 39 4a 08 74 30 be 01 00 00 00 31 c0 83 3d 12
0x000000354306799a:   bd 32 00 00 74 0c f0 0f b1 32 0f 85 20 01 00 00 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000012 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007fdac0378080 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00007fdac0378080 is an unknown value
RDX=0x6b6f6f4c24726573 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007fdac444e420 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fdac0008000
RBP=0x0000000000000012 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00007fdac04fea20 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007fdac04fea20 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007fdac444f700 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fdac0008000
R10=0x0000000000000012 is an unknown value
R11=0x00007fdac04fea33 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000012 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007fdac444e510 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fdac0008000
R15=0x00007fdac0008000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007fdac434f000,0x00007fdac4450000],  sp=0x00007fdac444e420,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x6798a]  fwrite+0x4a

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  prism.PrismNative.PN_PrintToFile(JLjava/lang/String;)V+0
j  prism.PrismFileLog.printToLog(Ljava/lang/String;)V+5
j  prism.PrismFileLog.print(Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
j  prism.PrismLog.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
j  prism.Prism.loadPRISMModel(Lparser/ast/ModulesFile;)V+82
j  prism.Prism.buildModel(Lparser/ast/ModulesFile;)Lprism/Model;+2
j  executor.PrismExecutor.start(I)V+76
j  executor.PrismExecutor.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+15
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Comment: I suggest trying update 31 instead of update 5 as this might be a bug which has been fixed.

Comment: @Peter, isn't awkward that it runs on my machine and it crashes on the server? Both have the same version of JVM.

Comment: I suggest you post complete `hs_err.log` crash dump, otherwise it would be a guess-game. Though I'm almost sure the problem is in poorly written PRISM library that you use. It does not perform proper validation of arguments and return values, so that `fwrite` is trying to access a closed or even NULL file handle. Check the first argument to  `PN_PrintToFile` if possible.

Comment: @apangin, could you please explain what do you mean by Prism (that's the name of the tool I am using)?

Comment: @STiGMa [Here](http://kamiframework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/%20kamiframework/KAMI/prism-3.3/src/prism/PrismNative.cc) I've found the source code for the problematic `PN_PrintToFile` native method that calls `fwrite`.

Comment: @apangin, for a moment I thought that you had magic powers and figured out "magically" that I am using Prism :)
Any idea if this can be resolved?
For me it's awkward that it works on my mac and not on server (linux). I will try later to run it on ubuntu to double check if the problem persists.

Comment: @STiGMa Yes. You have the source code. You know the function that fails. I've told you the possible reason (e.g. invalid FILE* pointer due to failed `fopen`). What else do you need to debug?

Comment: `si_addr=0x0000000000000000` in the crash report confirms the hypothesis about NULL argument to `fwrite`. This can happen if preceding `fopen` fails, for instance, due to No-Such-File or Permission-Denied error. Do you know what file is being written to?

Comment: @apangin, it's the output file where the results are stored

Comment: @STiGMa either the crash is random, or it happens consistently as something else is different between the client and server e.g. different OS version or hardware.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, apangin well it looks like there is a problem with linux libraries. I tried running a simple program (just a simple invocation of the API) on 3 different linux machines (2 servers and a workstation). It crashes at exactly the same command.

Comment: I guess the only way to figure out the cause of problem (i.e., NULL argument as parameter) is to do what @apangin suggested.

Comment: @STiGMa does it work on any of your Linux systems? Do you have access to the source, of a support person who does?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, no unfortunately it does not work on any Linux system. The source code is freely available. I am trying to do the debugging now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the assumption that you've compiled on the Mac, and now you've deployed on the Linux server.

Unlike pure Java, JNI code doesn't produce portable bytecode. You have to produce binary runtimes for each runtime environment you're targeting. So in this case you'll need one for whatever Linux version your server is running.

Probably the most simplest thing to do is compile it on the server if you can.

Comment: Not I'm afraid. The JNI libraries I use are linux-based (I am using the API of a tool which employs JNI). The only thing that I compiled on OSX was pure java to produce the jar file that runs the logic of the application.

Comment: You compiled your JNI stubs on the server?

Comment: No, I used the linux-based JNI stubs provided by the tool. It is already compiled for linux and osx. Check the update for the problematic frame.